# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{1+2^{(-1)^n}}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

Here is a problem I haven't met with yet and looks curious.
Find $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{1+2^{(-1)^n}}$$
Also help with this one would be appreciated
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k}$$
where k is an integer.
We know that the first limit converges because it's $<1< for ratio test.

Comment: $\sqrt[n]{1+2^{(-1)^n}} = \exp \big(\frac{1}{n}\log(1+2^{(-1)^n}) \big)$ is not defined for $n=2p+1$, $p\geq 0$. But if you choose the subsequence given by $n= 2p$, $p\geq 0$, then the limit is $1$.

Comment: @anonymus Are you sure it is not defined?

Comment: misread, thought it was $2\times (-1)^n$... thank you for correcting me. I'm getting tired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the squeeze theorem. Depending on whether $n$ is even or odd, we have respectively
$$
1+2^{(-1)^n} = \begin{cases}3&n \text{ even}\\
\frac{3}{2}&n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
$$
so that
$$
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{1/n} \leq \left(1+2^{(-1)^n}\right)^{1/n} \leq 3^{1/n}.
$$
The limit of both LHS and RHS when $n\to\infty$ is...?

---

For the second one, same approach. Since $k>0$ is a constant, you have
$$
n \leq \sum_{j=1}^n j^k \leq n^{k+1}
$$and thus
$$
n^{1/n} \leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^n j^k\right)^{1/n} \leq n^{(k+1)/n} = e^{(k+1)\frac{\ln n}{n}}.
$$
Again, both LHS and RHS have same limit.

Comment: I have to ask... It's $1$ in both cases?

Comment: Yes, it is.${}{}$

Comment: I just have this problems in a book and there aren't any answers

Comment: This gives no proof, but at least you can do a sanity check with Wolfram Alpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+(1%2B2%5E(-1)%5En)%5E(1%2Fn)+when+n-%3E+Infinity

Comment: All too easy.  +1

Comment: @Dr.MV "All too squeezy," I'd say.

Comment: That deserved PUNishment - time in the PUNitentiary .

Comment: @Dr.MV You guys pushed the limit...

Comment: @SimpleArt Now that was punny.